# Spark master Web Ui showing Spark worker information 0 in Cloudera Quick start Vmware

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

[image][image]
Spark Master WebUI is not showing spark worker informations, also the worker is running perfectly fine in Cloudera Quickstart VM 5.3.0.

Configuration file in Cloudera Quickstart vm :

```
export SPARK_LAUNCH_WITH_SCALA=0
export SPARK_LAUNCH_WITH_SCALA=0
export SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH=${SPARK_HOME}/lib
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=18080
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
export SPARK_WORKER_PORT=7078
export SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT=18081
export SPARK_WORKER_DIR=/var/run/spark/work
export SPARK_LOG_DIR=/var/log/spark
export SPARK_PID_DIR='/var/run/spark/'
```

Comment: same here. Any updates?

Comment: Hi i found the solution if you are using cloudera then add two lines in etc/spark/conf/Sparkenv.sh                                                              export SPARK_MASTER_HOST='quickstart.cloudera'
export SPARK_LOCAL_HOST='quickstart.cloudera'
After that restart the spark master and worker .YOu can see the worker in information in master now.

Comment: That is really helpful, you should put that comment as an answer and mark it completed, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hi I found the solution if you are using cloudera quickstart vm then add two lines in etc/spark/conf/Sparkenv.sh:

```
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST='quickstart.cloudera' 
export SPARK_LOCAL_HOST='quickstart.cloudera'
```

After that restart the spark master and worker. You can see the worker in information in master now.